# Creating a buoyant boat in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

I need to find a way to make a 3D boat, appear to be buoyant in the water. Currently I am using a boat with a flat bottom and making it slide along the terrain, which is just below the water. This is giving the illusion of buoyancy, but not really what I'm looking for.

The boat moves using

```
this.transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.smoothDeltaTime * ((speed) + 1));
```

The boat turns using

```
this.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward*Time.smoothDeltaTime*(int)(30*horizontal));
```

The boat has a **RigidBody** that uses gravity, does not interpolate, and has a Continuous Dynamic collision Detection. It also uses a convex **Mesh Collider**, with Smooth Sphere Collisions.

The Water has a **Box Collider** that is used as a trigger.

---

Now I need a way to make the boat seem to float in the water programmatically.
That means it

- Wobbles when it hits something
- Doesn't touch the bottom of the "river"
- Corrects its rotation to stay flat on the river *(doesn't stay crooked after hitting an island or other obstacle)*

I would like to do this so that I can give the base of my boat the correct shape so that it can have more realistic collisions with underwater obstacles.

Comment: First, if you want the boat to move physically correct you can't and you shouldn't move it via `transform.Translate` as this cause issues with objects that have a rigidy body and react to physics (read: is **not** set to kinematic). 

Reason: When you move an object inside another kinematic object, you will receive a heavy reaction, because 2 physical objects are inside each other and the physics has to push them away. The further away they clip in each other the stronger will the push back reaction be

Comment: i saw a page mentioning a couple of boat buoyancy scripts, like advanced and at least one was free, on the unity forums. to make boat bob and similar to a boat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additional to my comment, if really you want it to be buoyant, you have to make it non-kinematic and react to gravity and the water has to bee a volumetric mesh (or a box as you use, but that's less accurate, do not work with waves if you use water with wave effect).

Basically you'd want to add (at least) 4 objects to your boat and place rigidbody inside it and a script which will apply an upward force which is greater than your gravity.

Then in your `OnCollisionStay` method set a bool. Maybe something like this (on top of my head)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Buoyancy : MonoBehaviour {
    public float UpwardForce = 12.72f; // 9.81 is the opposite of the default gravity, which is 9.81. If we want the boat not to behave like a submarine the upward force has to be higher than the gravity in order to push the boat to the surface
    private bool isInWater = false;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collidier) {
        isInWater = true;
        rigidbody.drag = 5f;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider collidier) {
        isInWater = false;
        rigidbody.drag = 0.05f;
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        if(isInWater) {
            // apply upward force
            Vector3 force = transform.up * UpwardForce;
            this.rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(force, ForceMode.Acceleration);
            Debug.Log("Upward force: " + force+" @"+Time.time);
        }
    }
}
```

And place this on all 4 buoyancy objects (together with a collider or trigger of course). When the object is in water, it will push the boat upwards, if it's over the water, it will be pulled down by the gravity until it reaches water again where it will be pulled up again until it finds a balance.

P.S. If you want to move the boat, you will use the `this.rigidbody.AddForce(Vector.forward * 5, ForceMode.Force)` (or `ForceMode.Accelerate`) to move the boat

Comment: Tried it too. Instead of using OnTriggerStay, OnTriggerEnter/Exit gives better results. You may also need to play with the drag (i.e. increase drag while it's underwater and lower it while its over water)

Comment: How can I get the boat to correct itself then? I want it to rock, but not stay how it has been rotated when it hits something.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Buoyancy script](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/72974-Buoyancy-script/page5). Just add this to the boat, and add the water level (its y value) in the code. Also it is best to use addForce instead of translate to move the boat.

If you want to make the boat react more realistically, you should also put its center of gravity lower, this way it will "wobble" and it stays right side up.